# htaccess SEO Url Friendly

Tags: .htaccess, url, seo, url-rewriting

I have this:

```
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#!/$1 [L]
```

And I want to /signup to go rediect to index.php?a=signup

I tried

```
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ index.php?a=signup
```

And others but none works!

Comment: Just a guess at this point, but shouldn't it be `^/signup/?$` ? (Add a starting slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteRule ^signup/?$ index.php?a=signup [NC,L]
```

At the top after `RewriteBase /`

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on check mark on top-left of my answer.